# how do i get file name in folder document search

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I am using "Directory Loader" in Langhian for reading content.

```
loader = DirectoryLoader('../data/gauravCustomCvPdf/', glob='**/*.pdf')
documents = loader.load()
```

In search result I also need file name in which search is performed.
Ex. i have 50 cv in a folder the in search I have needed cv file name also with answer.